# APIs in Cloud Run and Nginx reverse proxy in VM

Tags: nginx, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-endpoints, api-gateway, google-cloud-run

I have deployed 6 different Flask based applications to Google Cloud Run. They work perfectly fine when I access them through the autogenerated URL. Now, I want to unify all 6 services under one domain name with different routes. 
 For example,
 
mydomain.com/user -> https://custom-user-asdtgthyju-de.a.run.app 
mydomain.com/product -> https://custom-product-asdtgthyju-de.a.run.app

Things I have tried
**1. Nginx deployed in a separate VM with reverse proxy to the cloud run URLs**
Not working, same configuration-same code deployed in regular VMs work but for cloud run deployments shows route "/user" not found

**2. Cloud Endpoints using ESPv2**
https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/openapi/get-started-cloud-run
Got this working as per my requirement, but not able to pass the custom headers, like I use X-API-KEY for authentication, it doesn't even get to the Cloud Run. It is being stripped off by ESPv2 itself.

Please help, how I can configure a reverse proxy/ API gateway in front of cloud run services. Has anyone tried **External Nginx to Cloud Run** mapping?

Thanks

Comment: Can you include your  Cloud Endpoints configuration file to see how we can help to get it working?

Comment: Did you finally found a way to do it?

Comment: @lewislbr I followed petomalina's answer and I guess that is the only way to do it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@petomalina's answer is the easiest if your Cloud Run service is public. If it's not, it won't work as per [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70511273/1086540)

If your service is `internal`, I tried OP's #1 option of putting an nginx reverse proxy in front and was getting the same error: 404.

The issue is caused by the `Host` header having the host of the proxy, not of the Cloud Run service. The fix is to configure nginx to override the Host header:

```
upstream my-foo {
    server  foo.run.app:443;
}
location /foo/ {
    proxy_pass  https://my-foo;
    proxy_set_header Host foo.run.app;
    include /etc/nginx/proxy_params;
    proxy_ssl_session_reuse on;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The easiest way to get a single domain with URL routing would be to use [Firebase Hosting and its's redirection to Cloud Run](https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/cloud-run). You can add your domain to the Firebase hosting and redirect to a particular Cloud Run services based on their source (URL).

Comment: Does this actually do anything beyond what standard Cloud Run already does? You can use custom domains directly on Cloud Run, but the current version does not support path mapping, so you need a subdomain per service.

Comment: NVM, I found it: https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/full-config#direct_requests_to_a_cloud_run_container

This probably does do what you are looking for.