# Can Firebase Hosting proxy an internal Cloud Run service?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, reverse-proxy, firebase-hosting, google-cloud-run

I have a Cloud Run service that's working fine when I send requests from inside my VPC network (from a GCE instance). The service is configured as an internal service with this in the YAML

```
    run.googleapis.com/ingress: internal
    run.googleapis.com/ingress-status: internal
```

Is it possible to still proxy it with Firebase Hosting as specified [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/cloud-run)?

When I try, I get exactly the same error that I get when I try to contact the Cloud Run service from outside the VPC: `403 Forbidden` but I'm not sure if this is just not possible or I'm missing a configuration/i-am permission somewhere to allow Firebase Hosting to invoke the Cloud Run service

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firebase Hosting makes requests to Cloud Run services over public networks. It is not currently possible to use internal ingress with Firebase Hosting.

Comment: Thank you @Michael. any sources supporting that? that was my feeling too but i can't find anything saying as much

Comment: It's not in the docs, but I work on Firebase :)